# robot_pose_ekf pubs on robot_pose_ekf/odom but not on robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, odom-combined, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am supplying odometry and Imu data to robot_pose_ekf and it is publishing the transform to base_footprint and the topic robot_pose_ekf/odom correctly.  It advertises the topic robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined but rostopic echo shows that nothing is being published on that topic.  So I am concerned that it is just using the odometry data sent to it and ignoring the Imu data.

The documentation:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf

says it should just be publishing the transform and robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined, not mentioning the topic robot_pose_ekf/odom.

So, what's up?  Is the topic robot_pose_ekf/odum what was previously the topic robot_pose_EKF/odom_combined?  Or do I need to debug some more to determine why the combined topic is not getting data published?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74875/robot_pose_ekf-pubs-on-robot_pose_ekf/odom-but-not-on-robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2013-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answered.  It is because I used the example launch file from the wiki page.  In that launch file, the parameter "output_frame" is set to value = "odom"
The odom_estimation_node.cpp file uses that parameter to determine the topic advertised, with the default being "odom_combined"

I found it confusing because I was thinking that "output frame" would refer to the tf frame not the published topic name.

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2013-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-09-10**:
You're right, it is confusing. The parameter `output_frame` refers to *both* the tf frame and the name of the published topic.